# How Do I Access 127.0.0.1 in The Host(win8.1) From VMware(win xp)?

Tags: vmware-workstation, localhost

I have windows 8.1 installed and I am running VMware worksation with XP as the guest OS.

I am a web developer and I installed a webserver(wampserver/php/apache)  on The win 8.1
I can reach to my website by 127.0.0.1 address.

Now...How can I reach to my website (on localhost on win 8.1 with 127.0.0.1) in XP os?

I can connect to internet on xp os but 127.0.0.1 not working.

Answer (score 1):

look into the IP mapping of the virtual networks.

In the toolbar of workstation, there is somewhere an option to configure virtual networks.

The virtual adapters subnets are set there. The x.x.x.1 of those networks points to the host if its a host only network or a bridge.

You can not connect to 127.0.0.1 from the virtual machine. You need to set the server to one of the other external host adresses like 192.168.1.0/24 in a subnet that is shared with the guest.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to give the guest OS it's own IP by changing the VMware's network setting for that guest host from the default "NAT" to "Bridged". Then your VM XP will be able to use the Win 8.1's actual IP address as if it were just another box on your LAN.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm newbie in network. I changed  "NAT" to "Bridged" in xp vmware setting...But I cannot access to 127.0.0.1 form XP yet...

Comment: Right, because that means to  stay within  the local machine (XP, not the host). Get the address from your Win8.1 (in a terminal window, type "ipconfig" to get it's address) and then use that address in the WinXP to get to the host's webserver.

Comment: unfortunatly I couldn't do it. I taked a pic form setting and IP config...http://i57.tinypic.com/29c6j4l.png

Comment: Do you have an exception in your host's firewall to accept the port you are using for apache? (Typically 80). Check if you can reach the host from another machine on that local network.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot.

Localhost is **local** to each host.

YOu have:
A win 8 host (with webserver) with its own 127.0.0.1 loopback.
A win XP guest with its own 127.0.0.1 loopback.

These two are not the same. And in many cases (e.g. windows) they are coded to never reach an real outside network. They cannot communicate with each other.

If you want to communicate then bind your webserver to a different IP.